# What is the Rails convention for routes with empty paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here's the context:

```
scope 'foo' do
  get '', to: 'foo#index'
  get 'bar', to: 'foo#bar'
  get 'baz', to: 'foo#baz'
end
```

Does the `get ''` route make sense here, or is there a convention for this kind of route?
And is it necessary to have a slash (`/`) prefix e.g. `get '/'` or `scope '/foo'`?

Comment: `get '/'` is what I've most commonly seen, fwiw.

Comment: While @JoshBrody is correct most will use `get '/'`. You can also use `root` to indicate the same. e.g. `scope :foo { root to: 'foo#index'}`

Comment: @engineersmnky sounds like an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally base routing will be shown as

```
scope :foo do
  get '/', to: 'controller#action'
end
```

but the `root` method also respects the current scope so you could use it as follows

```
scope :foo do
  root to: 'controller#action'
end
```

Both options will result in identical routes.